# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'grower' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button which calls a function 'SaveNewOpportunity'. In component file I have defined the function. 
However on Clicking the button I  am getting error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'grower' of undefined
```

HTML Code:

```
  <button
   mat-flat-button
   color="accent"
   (click)="saveNewOpportunity()"
   [disabled]="isEdit">
   Save </button>
```

Typescript code:-

```
saveNewOpportunity() {
    this.opportunity.projectId = this.project.id;
    this.opportunity.opportunityId = null;
    this.opportunity.oppName = this.opportunity.oppName;
    this.opportunity.description = this.opportunity.description;
    this.opportunity.formula = this.opportunity.formula;
    this.opportunity.createdDate = this.opportunity.createdDate;
    this.opportunity.createdBy = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
    this.opportunity.ptnlFormula = this.ptnl_formula;
    this.opportunity.isonmain = this.opportunity.isonmain;
    this.opportunity.active = this.opportunity.active;
    this.opportunity.elgblFormula = this.eligible_formula;
    this.opportunity.oppAction = this.opportunity.oppAction;
    this.opportunity.flatCutOff = this.thresholdGroups.grower.cutOff;
    this.opportunity.stopperCutOff = this.thresholdGroups.stopper.cutOff;
    this.opportunity.dropperCutOff = this.thresholdGroups.dropper.cutOff;

    // loader
    this.isLoadingResults = true;
    this.recommendationService
        .saveNewOpportunity(this.opportunity)
        .subscribe(
            response => {
                let newOppData: any = response;

                if (this.opportunityList !== undefined) {
                    this.opportunityList.push(newOppData);
                }
                this.oppList = new MatTableDataSource<any>(
                    this.opportunityList
                );
                this.snakbar.statusBar(
                    'New Opportunity saved successfully',
                    'Success'
                );
                this.isOpportunityCreationScreen = true;
                this.isLoadingResults = false; //loader
            },
            error => {
                this.isLoadingResults = false; //loader
                this.snakbar.statusBar(
                    'New Opportunity save failed',
                    'Failure'
                );
            }
        );
}
```

I can't seem to locate the problem.The error shown in browser console is

```
OpportunityComponent.html:734 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'grower' of undefined
at OpportunityComponent.push../src/app/layout/opportunity/opportunity.component.ts.OpportunityComponent.saveNewOpportunity (opportunity.component.ts:772)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (OpportunityComponent.html:737)
at handleEvent (core.js:21652)
```

Comment: It seems that your `this.thresholdGroups` in undefined. Please check if it was initialized correctly. You cannot get `grower` because you are trying to get this value from undefined

Comment: No I have imported thresholdGroups and created instance of it. I didnt post the entire component.ts code because its too lengthy.

Comment: Ok, I didn`t catch that thing: ```this.recommendationService.saveNewOpportunity(this.opportunity)```. The signature of your method does not include any parameters, but you pass arguments here. Maybe you have problems caused by context lost.

Comment: @Florian You are right, my fault )

Comment: @saad in your html check around your line 734, you try to use `grower` property ?

Comment: `this.thresholdGroups` is not initialized correctly. Can you show how you initialize it?

Comment: Maybe inside your html-template you need use `?.` operator

Comment: import {
    ThresholdStats,
    ThresholdGroups
} from '../custom-components/threshold/threshold.model';                                            export class OpportunityComponent implements OnInit {                                             thresholdGroups: ThresholdGroups;

Comment: @saad You just declared your thresholdGroups, but did not initialize it

Comment: @Florian No I have posted my html code...I have not used or written any extra code in my html

Comment: @OleksiiMiroshnyk How do I initialize it then???

Comment: @OleksiiMiroshnyk How do use ?. inside html .... I don't know

Comment: @saad ```thresholdGroups: ThresholdGroups = new ThresholdGroups()```

Comment: Thankyou @OleksiiMiroshnyk I initalised it and its working now

Comment: @saad Yeah, cool :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the suggestion by @OleksiiMiroshnyk
Changing my code from this

```
thresholdGroups: ThresholdGroups
```

to

```
thresholdGroups: ThresholdGroups = new ThresholdGroups()
```

did the trick.
Although it used to work initially but I don't know what changed.
Anyway creating instance of object like OleksiiMiroshnyk suggested me solved the problem.